# if you have the latest version of jquery, is livequery still useful?

Tags: jquery, livequery

From what I understand livequery is for maintaining your events after DOM changes.

Does not the latest build of jquery already support this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is still useful. `live()` only works on certain events, while `livequery()` can be bound to any event the user's browser provides.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

> **Possible event values:** `click, dblclick,  mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, keydown, keypress, keyup`
>
> **Currently not supported:** `blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit`

Note that also unsupported are touch events like `touchstart, touchend`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One useful feature that `livequery()` provides while `live()` doesn't is the ability to fire a custom function every time a new element is matched (and/or an element is no longer matched).

From the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery):

> Live Query also has the ability to
>   fire a function (callback) when it
>   matches a new element and another
>   function (callback) for when an
>   element is no longer matched. This
>   provides ultimate flexibility and
>   untold use-cases. For example the
>   following code uses a function based
>   Live Query to implement the jQuery
>   hover helper method and remove it when
>   the element is no longer matched.

```
$('li') 
    .livequery(function(){ 
    // use the helper function hover to bind a mouseover and mouseout event 
        $(this) 
            .hover(function() { 
                $(this).addClass('hover'); 
            }, function() { 
                $(this).removeClass('hover'); 
            }); 
    }, function() { 
        // unbind the mouseover and mouseout events 
        $(this) 
            .unbind('mouseover') 
            .unbind('mouseout'); 
    });
```